# What link of realsense D455 should I put inside an existing robot arm urdf file?

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to add realsense d455 model and its tf to an existing robot arm urdf. What link should I add to my robot arm urdf ?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414460/what-link-of-realsense-d455-should-i-put-inside-an-existing-robot-arm-urdf-file?/) by [TapleFlib](https://answers.ros.org/users/144407/tapleflib/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2023-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can create parent link on the top of base_link( as a child) name realsense_camera_link, and you can add that to robot arm, that's also a good practice if you are working with multiple sensors.

OR

I would suggest picking a (Parent link)base link. All child link transformations will be derived form the parent.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2023-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TapleFlib](https://answers.ros.org/users/144407/tapleflib/) on 2023-04-21**:
Got it, thanks so much!